# VBA Line Input vs Input

Tags: file-io, excel, input, vba

I want to read a file written by c where each line is seperated by /n. I want read that file and compare it with data on excel.
I used `input #1, data` .
But I want to read a line with ","(comma), So i used `Line Input #1, data`.

when i check that "data" with data on excel, though they are same, its saying false.

```
Activecell="KVK"
Line Input #1,data
msgbox ActiveCell=data
```

is printing false even if data is KVK.

Thanks and Regards for Helping in advance,
Vamshi krishna

```
Dim fpath, fnum, s
fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename
fnum = FreeFile
Open fpath For Input As fnum
Range("A1").Activate

Do While Not EOF(fnum)
Line Input #fnum, s
'Input #fnum, s

MsgBox s & " = " & ActiveCell & "  "
MsgBox s = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

.txt has

```
12
13
14
```

data in first column

```
12
13
14
```

Comment: Kindly debug and check the value in data

Comment: @user2063626 Sorry for previous version, I tried to modify my question. And i tried above statements. My problem is to know about Line Input vs Input if string is not having comma

Comment: Even my Heading its VBA Line Input vs Input

Comment: @user2063626 This is not happening when am doing in new workbook. But happening in my project. Could you please help me.

Comment: Kindly share your entire code or the file

Comment: @user2063626 Please check the question I updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub InputImage()

    Dim FileNum As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim fpath As String, s As String, cellVal As String

    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename


    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open fpath For Input As #FileNum

    i = 1
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, s    ' read in data 1 line at a time

        cellVal = CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)

        MsgBox s & " = " & cellVal & "  "
        MsgBox s = cellVal
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        i = i + 1
    Wend


End Sub
```

If you check in watch window the data type of cell(i,1).Value is showing Variant/Double. So there is need to convert into string.

[image]

Comment: Thanx A Million. Its really working. But why to convert to string?

Answer (score 0):

Or use the TextStream in the Scripting library, it's much better.

And please close the file when your finished with it, you must be the type of person who doesn't put the milk back in the fridge when your finished with it and just spoils it for everyone.

Comment: Its ok.I close it. Dont worry its not milk. I just made a sample code, to explain my problem.